# Select Multiple Columns based on multiple columns from same table in MySql

Tags: mysql, select, case, inner-join, union-all

[image]

I want to return 3 columns Dtls (Details), Purchase_amount as credit, Sale_amount as debit

But When Purchase_id = 3, Purchase_amount must be selected and Sale_amount must be 0, and vice-versa.

The required result:

[image]

The required result against the number 3:

If I try

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        select c.Sale_amount as debit 
        from yarn c 
        where c.Sale_id=3
    ) A, 
    (
        select c2.Purchase_amount as credit 
        from yarn c2 
        where c2.Purchase_id=3
    ) B;
```

it provides queer results.

This does not work:

```
SELECT A as debit, B as credit 
FROM (
        select c.Sale_amount as debit 
        from yarn c 
        where c.Sale_id=3
    ) A, 
    (
        select c2.Purchase_amount as credit 
        from yarn c2 
        where c2.Purchase_id=3
    ) B;
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly, your goal is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the table to get only the rows with `Purchase_id` or `Sale_id` equal to 3 and use `CASE` expressions to get the columns `Credit` and `Debit`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Purchase_id = 3 THEN Purchase_amount ELSE 0 END AS Credit,
       CASE WHEN Sale_id = 3 THEN Sale_amount ELSE 0 END AS Debit
FROM yarn
WHERE 3 IN (Purchase_id, Sale_id);
```